# Microsoft Teams: How to get the user's activity stream (notifications)?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Is there a way to get the notifications from a user's activity stream in Microsoft Teams? Like "all notifications" and "unread notifications"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not yet supported. It will be, but it's not there yet as of October 2017.